Celery Not able to connect to SQS using boto3 credentials
I'm trying to use Celery with SQS with the below config. But I receive InvalidClientToken error. Could some one help me to resolve this?
I'm using celery[sqs]==5.3.6, Kombu==5.3.7
# Celery configuration
SQS_QUEUE_URL = f'https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/{settings.aws_account}/{settings.celery_worker_queue}' 
result_backend = f'db+postgresql://{settings.pg_db_config.user}:{settings.pg_db_config.pwd}@{settings.pg_db_config.host}:5432/{settings.pg_db_config.db_name}'
pg_db_conn_string = f"postgresql://{settings.pg_db_config.user}:{settings.pg_db_config.pwd}@{settings.pg_db_config.host}:{settings.pg_db_config.port}/{settings.pg_db_config.db_name}"

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='ar-se-sbx')

app = Celery(
    'worker',
    broker_url=f"sqs://",
    backend=result_backend,
    task_default_queue=settings.celery_worker_queue,
    broker_connection_retry_on_startup=True,
    broker_transport_options={
        "region": "us-east-2",
        'predefined_queues': {
            'celery-worker-1':{
                'url': SQS_QUEUE_URL,
                'access_key_id': session.get_credentials().access_key,
                'secret_access_key': session.get_credentials().secret_key,
            }
        }
    },
    task_create_missing_queues=False,
)

Error:
--------------- celery@XXXXXv5.3.6 (emerald-rush)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.22631-SP0 2024-09-21 17:40:48
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         worker:0x1f0861a8370
- ** ---------- .> transport:   sqs://localhost//
- ** ---------- .> results:     postgresql://root:**@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (solo)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery-worker-1  exchange=celery-worker-1(direct) key=celery-worker-1


[tasks]
  . LANG_GUARD

[2024-09-21 17:40:48,995: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to sqs://localhost//
[2024-09-21 17:40:49,832: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: ClientError('An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetQueueAttributes operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.')


If these are temporary credentials from STS, rather than persistent credentials from IAM, then you need to provide access key, secret key, and session token.

Is this code running on an EC2 instance or your own computer? How are you providing the credentials to your app? Where did you obtain the credentials? Does the Access Key start with AKIA, or something else?

@JohnRotenstein the code is running on my local. I have aws profiles setup on my local. I login using those profiles which will pull the credential to my local. I'm using the same profile name in the code to access the access key, secret key. Access Key starts with ASIA

You need to also pass the session token. See https://blog.gurjot.dev/aws-access-keys

Based on IAM identifiers - AWS Identity and Access Management:

ASIA: Temporary (AWS STS) access key IDs use this prefix, but are unique only in combination with the secret access key and the session token.

This means that you are using temporary credentials, typically obtained when assuming an IAM Role. Temporary credentials have three parts:

Access Key (like a username)
Secret Key (like a password)
Session Token (used only with temporary credentials)

Therefore, you should use something like:
                'access_key_id': session.get_credentials().access_key,
                'secret_access_key': session.get_credentials().secret_key,
                'session_token': session.get_credentials().session_token

(I'm not sure what variable name the celery worker is expecting for session_token, so it might be slightly different.)
Alternatively, you can store credentials from an IAM User in your local machine, which would only use an Access Key and Secret Key (without the Session Token).

I tries passing in the token as well and no luck. I'm not sure if Kombu supports session token. I feel this is more of a Kombu issue than aws.

The other option is to use IAM User credentials, which do not use a Session Token.

You need to move all access credentials to a higher level by using the broker_transport_options. This is the example:
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Queue

app = Celery(
    "worker",
    broker_url="sqs://",
    broker_connection_retry_on_startup=True,
    broker_transport_options={
        "region": "us-east-2",
        "aws_access_key_id": session.get_credentials().access_key,
        "aws_secret_access_key": session.get_credentials().secret_key,
        "aws_session_token": session.get_credentials().session_token,
        "predefined_queues": {
            settings.celery_worker_queue: {
                "url": SQS_QUEUE_URL,
            }
        },
    },
    task_queues=[
        Queue(settings.celery_worker_queue, routing_key=settings.celery_worker_queue),
    ],
    task_create_missing_queues=False,
)

